# How to get records with in fixed date interval in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The federal aviation authority wants to know how many types of aircraft each of your pilots (employee only i.e. EMP) is **currently** certified (qualifies) to fly. Assume that the validity of a certification is only **for one year**. So, list the pilots and **the number** of types of aircraft each is currently qualified to fly (date_certified). Please list pilot full name, license number, and number of types s/he is **currently** qualified (certified) to fly. (hint: SYSDATE returns today's date like date() in MS Access. (SYSDATE +30) is 30 days from today).

**HERE IS THE PILOT TABLE:**

```
pilot_nbr, license_nbr, last_name, first_name, title, address, phone, office_nbr, contract_type, salary, manager_nbr  

'701', '7111', 'Dark', 'Jack', '1st officer', '6 street', '6042233445', '789', 'PTE', '145000.00', NULL
'702', '7222', 'Mack', 'Bill', '1st officer', '7 street', '6043344556', '890', 'EMP', '155000.00', '701'
'703', '7333', 'Cheung', 'Charles', '2nd officer', '8 street', '6044455667', '503', 'PTE', '140000.00', '701'
'704', '7444', 'Gordon', 'Greg', '1st officer', '9 street', '6045566778', '123', 'EMP', '125000.00', '701'
'705', '7555', 'Basso', 'Nicki', '2nd officer', '5 street', '6046677889', '223', 'EMP', '163000.00', '701'
'706', '7666', 'Vettel', 'Sebast', '1st officer', '5 street', '6046677800', '523', 'EMP', '199000.00', '701'
'707', '7777', 'Hawke', 'Mike', '2nd officer', '7 street', '6046677326', '423', 'EMP', '139000.00', '701'
```

**HERE IS THE QUALIFIES TABLE:**

```
pilot_nbr, plane_type, date_certified  

'701', 'DE Prop', '2013-08-14'
'701', 'SE Prop', '2013-04-10'
'702', 'DE Prop', '2013-02-22'
'702', 'SE Jet', '2013-04-10'
'702', 'SE Prop', '2013-06-21'
'703', 'DE Prop', '2013-04-10'
'703', 'SE Jet', '2013-04-10'
'703', 'SE Prop', '2013-04-10'
'704', 'DE Prop', '2013-06-12'
'704', 'ME Jet', '2013-08-21'
'704', 'SE Jet', '2013-06-15'
'704', 'SE Prop', '2013-04-10'
```

**HERE IS WHAT I TRIED (DON'T KNOW IF IT IS CORRECT)**

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, license_nbr, Count(first_name) As 'No of types of airplane certified to fly'
FROM pilot, qualifies 
WHERE pilot.pilot_nbr=qualifies.pilot_nbr AND contract_type='EMP' AND date_certified >=  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY first_name, last_name
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: How about posting your expected results?

Comment: Buddy, the query which I wrote will return no results and I think it should because there is no pilot which is currently certified to fly this is 2016 and their certified date if you see is in 2013 and valid for 1 year. Please correct me if I understood bad because that's why I am asking? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Hope this will solve your task...

SELECT p.first_name, p.last_name, p.license_nbr, Count(q.plane_type) As 'No of types of airplane certified to fly'
FROM pilot p inner join qualifies q on p.pilot_nbr = q.pilot_nbr
WHERE p.contract_type='EMP' AND DATE_SUB(q.date_certified, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) > CURDATE()
GROUP BY p.first_name, p.last_name, p.license_nbr;
```